# VBA How to print out cells from different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to print out two cells next to each other from two different sheets.
Here is what I have made so far.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Selection.Offset(0, 4).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count + 0, _
 Selection.Columns.Count + 0).Select
   Dim a As Range
   Set a = Selection
   Dim b As Range
   Set b = Worksheets("setup").Range("A1")
   Set b = Selection
   Dim c As Range
   Set c = ?
   c.PrintPreview
End Sub
```

How do I do it?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you are trying to do. Don't you have an example/screenshot? Right now you set a range, reset it, set another one etc. It doesn't make sense right now.

Comment: Why do you use VBA for that? You can't print from two sheets onto one page. Use a helper sheet with formulas that pull `=Sheet1!A1` and `=Sheet2!A1` and print the helper sheet.

Comment: Are the two Worksheets containing the single cells in the same Workbook?